# Java Mail API Relaying denied error

Tags: jakarta-mail, aix

I am facing some weird problem, I have installed the SMTP server on my AIX box and I am successful to send email using the following command:
mailx -s "Hola Mundo" email@domain.com < /tmp/test.txt

But when I am sending the email using the javamail api I am getting following exception, could you help me how to resolve that.

```
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is: 
    javax.mail.SendFailedException: 550 5.7.1 <email@domain.com>... Relaying denied

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:632)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:306)

    at SendMailUsage.main(SendMailUsage.java:59)
```

and I am sure my email address is perfect one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been resolved by modifying the sendMail.cf file on the server side. My aix admin informed me that it was due to some DNS issue, will update the solution as soon as I hear from him

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [RFC 2821](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821) (Simple Mail Transfer Protocol), especially the part about STMP replies: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821#section-4.2

Status reply starting with 5xx indicates a permanent error. In your case your SMTP server is not configured to route mails to your given destination address.